# Large name field in POST request different on the server

Tags: php, apache, post, opencart

This is an odd bug that stops customers being able to change the quantities in their basket.

OpenCart saves selected product data in the cart array like:

```
[product_id:base64(serialized(option_data))]
```

The website itself has a custom product builder using the jQuery plugin Fancy Product Designer and the product data is stored in an option field.

On the cart page the customers have to option to remove or change the quantities in their basket. The default functionality of this page in OpenCart uses a form to adjust all the quantities and a link to remove the product from the cart with a query string.

The quantities are adjusted with a quantities field array e.g.

```
[quantity] => Array (
    [product_id:option_data] => quantity
    [391:YToxOntpOjg3NTtzOjQ6IjI4MjIiO30=:] => 2
)
```

However, when the option data is exceptionally large, that individual item is no longer in the quantity array and appears like:

```
[quantity_319:YToyOntpOjEyMTc7czo1ODcyOiJZVG94T250cE9qQTdZVG96T250ek9qVTZJb...]
```

and 2 other fields appear in the post request:

```
[x] => 6
[y] => 15
```

And the other items appear as normal in the [quantity] array.

Any ideas what is causing this?

(Normally they are removed from the cart in a get request e.g. /cart?remove=391:YToxOntpOjg3NTtzOjQ6IjI4MjIiO30=: but the get request was too long so I added a function that creates a form based on that link and submits it. This works for the large items as well)

Comment: The X and Y field can indicate an input field is an image type. Does this only happen when you POST the form with an exceptionally large value?

Comment: Yes, the 'update' button is a input type image (and whether the x and y gets sent seems to be dependant on the browser)